# LINQ select with many ToList inside takes too much time

Tags: c#, performance, linq, profiling

I've below `select` with `LINQ` query that takes too much time If I do `ToList` inside `Select` on `AsQueryable`.

**Approch 1**

**Takes approx 10s**

***This is simplest representation of my data with different ToList()***

Below `MYTABLE` has one to many relationship with `COLUMN`(another table) which has `Description` field

**using profiler query has UNION ALL for all ToList but query itself execute within 100ms, seems like it takes to parse by C#**

```
  // Project into usable data and enumerate
            var enumerated = await this.Context.MYTABLE.AsQueryable().Where(some condition).Select(x => new
            {
                Study1 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description1).ToList(),
                Study2 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description2).ToList(),
                Study3 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description3).ToList(),
                Study4 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description4).ToList(),
                Study5 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description5).ToList()
            }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            var results = enumerated.Select(o => new
            {
                Result1 = string.Join(", ", o.Study1),
                Result2 = string.Join(", ", o.Study2),
                Result3 = string.Join(", ", o.Study3),
                Result4 = string.Join(", ", o.Study4),
                Result5 = string.Join(", ", o.Study5),
            }).ToList();

            return results;
```

**Approch 2**

**Takes approx 2s**

**using profiler query is very small compare to previous, around 1/5 lines**

```
// Project into usable data and enumerate
        var enumerated = await this.Context.MYTABLE.AsQueryable().Where(some condition).Select(x => new
        {
            x.COLUMN
        }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        var results = enumerated.Select(o => new
        {
            Result1 = string.Join(", ", o.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description1).ToList()),
            Result2 = string.Join(", ", o.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description2).ToList()),
            Result3 = string.Join(", ", o.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description3).ToList()),
            Result4 = string.Join(", ", o.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description4).ToList()),
            Result5 = string.Join(", ", o.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description5).ToList()),
        }).ToList();

        return results;
```

Why **Approch 2** takes less time and query is also simpler then 1?

Is there any suggestion to improve `LINQ` performance

***Edit***

I notice in **Approch 2** it will call `database` multiple times for subsequent `ToList()` but still with all those calculation, `Database` retrieves within few milliseconds while C# take much more time.

**Approch 3**

This is also take around `2s`.

I just did `ToList` first in Approch 1.

```
 // Project into usable data and enumerate
  var enumerated2 =  await this.Context.MYTABLE.AsQueryable().Where(some condition).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            var enumerated = enumerated2.Select(x => new
            {
                Study1 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description1).ToList(),
                Study2 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description2).ToList(),
                Study3 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description3).ToList(),
                Study4 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description4).ToList(),
                Study5 = x.COLUMN.Select(j => j.Description5).ToList()
            }).ToList()

            var results = enumerated.Select(o => new
            {
                Result1 = string.Join(", ", o.Study1),
                Result2 = string.Join(", ", o.Study2),
                Result3 = string.Join(", ", o.Study3),
                Result4 = string.Join(", ", o.Study4),
                Result5 = string.Join(", ", o.Study5),
            }).ToList();

            return results;
```

I don't understand why `Approch 3` took less time then `Approch 1` where only difference is performing `ToList` method.

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToList()` twice on `StudyX`? Once in first select, and again in the results select.

Comment: @John question updated

Comment: Entity framework? entity framework core?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you need to call `.ToList()` twice? Remove the first one, that will help a bit.
2. Try using `.Include("Tablename")`. You can read about it here: https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/improving-performance-with-linq-b478cd77d105

This is probably the so-called "n+1 problem" you are facing. You can read about it here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/common-entity-framework-problems-n-1/

Comment: I tried with `.Include("COLUMN").Include("COLUMN.Description1")` still no luck.

Comment: You should not write column's names inside Include(..). There should be tables' names. You need to "include" all the tables you need to be joined to  execute your query. Something like: .Unclude("Table1").Unclude("Table2") etc. I edited my answer and included a link which describes the problem you are facing. Check that out.

Comment: Hi @Sofia thanks for help but using `Include` didn't make any performance improvement for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Query doesn't seem to be complicated though. Have you tried executing raw SQL query?

Comment: Yeah, raw SQL is pretty much faster (within 200ms)